# Collection in resultMap performance issue with mybatis

Tags: sql, performance, collections, mybatis

I have list in my class, therefore I used collection tag when mapping result. Here is an example code:

```
<select id="retrieveClassRoomsWithStudents" resultMap="classroomMapper">
    SELECT CLS.CLASSROOMCODE, CLS.CLASSROOMNAME
    FROM TMP.CLASSROOM CLS
    ORDER BY CLS.CLASSROOMNAME
</select>

<select id="retrieveStudents" resultMap="studentMapper" parameterType="Integer" >
    SELECT STD.CLASSROOMCODE, STD.STUDENTNUMBER, STD.STUDENTNAME
    FROM TMP.STUDENTS STD
    WHERE STD.CLASSROOMCODE = #{CLASSROOMCODE}
    ORDER BY STD.STUDENTNUMBER
</select>

<resultMap id="classroomMapper" type="ClassroomEntity" >
    <result property="classroomName" column="CLASSROOMNAME" />
    <result property="classroomCode" column="CLASSROOMCODE" />
    <collection property="studentList"  column="CLASSROOMCODE" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="StudentEntity" select="retrieveStudents" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="studentMapper" type="StudentEntity" >
    <result property="classroomCode" column="CLASSROOMCODE"/>
    <result property="studentNumber" column="STUDENTNUMBER"/>
    <result property="studentName" column="STUDENTNAME"/>
</resultMap>
```

I have around 200 classes and 10.000 students. "retrieveClassRoomsWithStudents" method runs for 20 seconds. I've tried left outer join to reduce query count. Single query runs in 70 ms, however resultmapping again takes around 20 seconds. Is there any way to improve this? Caching is no option and I am asked to return all students in one response.

Answer (score 1):

this is the famous 1+N select problem. you can use nested resultmap to solve it like this:

```
<resultMap id="classroomMapper" type="ClassroomEntity" >
    <result property="classroomName" column="CLASSROOMNAME" />
    <result property="classroomCode" column="CLASSROOMCODE" />
    <collection property="studentList"  resultMap="studentMapper" />
</resultMap>
```

Comment: good, but in order to run properly, the classroomCode property must be added as id tag instead result tag. This let Mybatis groups the results as expected.